# Eclipse: is there a shortcut for changing the order of methods in a class?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

In Eclipse, is there a shortcut for moving a certain method up or down the method list in a class, without having to cut and paste it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Window-->Show View->Outline
```

In `Outline` view change the order of methods with drag and drop

Answer (score 1):

You can select the Method and press

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>